# What does "Current Installation" in Eclipse mean?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, adt

I know this may sound like an English question. Let me explain.  The following screenshots were obtained by Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details. You can see the current installation of the Installation History tab does not match Installed Software. I am asking this because I have just installed the latest ADT, and seen some weird behaviors.

[image]

[image]